# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tempID' was corrupted

Tags: c, variables, stack, runtime, stack-corruption

I recently started coding in c, and during coding I encountered this run-time error which I can't find the solution to. It either displays this runtime error, or else stops after the `scanf` in the case where the customer is found, you choose what you want to edit, and then enter the new information.

Example:

- inputted ID:322993
- FOUND
- Pressed [1] to edit the ID
- Input the new ID
- *program gets stuck*

Here is the code:

```
void modifyCustomer(){
    int counter=0;
    long int tempID=0;
    flag found = false;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter Customer ID\n");
    scanf("%lld", &tempID);
    do{
        char option_str[200];
        int option = 0;
        char *not_valid;
        if(tempID == customers[counter].customerID){
            printf("Customer found!\n");
            found = true;
            do{
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Choose what to modify:\n 1. ID\n 2. Name\n 3. Surname\n 4. Address\n 5. Mobile\nOption: ");
                scanf("%s", &option_str);
                option = strtol(option_str, &not_valid, 10);
                fflush(stdin);
                if (*not_valid != '\0') {
                    printf("%s is not valid.\n", not_valid);
                } else{
                    switch(option){
                    case 1:
                        printf("Enter new ID:\n");
                        scanf("%d\n", &customers[counter].customerID);
                        printf("Customer Modified Successfully!\n");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        printf("Enter new Name:\n");
                        scanf("%s\n", &customers[counter].customerName);
                        printf("Customer Modified Successfully!\n");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        printf("Enter new Surname:\n");
                        scanf("%s\n", &customers[counter].customerSurname);
                        printf("Customer Modified Successfully!\n");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("Enter new Address:\n");
                        scanf("%s\n", &customers[counter].customerAddress);
                        printf("Customer Modified Successfully!\n");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        printf("Enter new Mobile:\n");
                        scanf("%lld\n", &customers[counter].customerMobile);
                        printf("Customer Modified Successfully!\n");
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("You did not enter a valid Number. Please re-enter your Input \n");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }while((option <1) || (option > 5));
        }
        else{
            counter++;
        }
    }while((found != true) && (counter < (custNum-1)));
    if (found == false)
        printf("Customer not found!\n");
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Doesn't matter on MSVC.  The code is trying to stuff a 64 pound pig in a 32 pound poke.  The format specifier must be %ld.

Comment: what abt second argument of strtol(). i.e not_valid, it is de-referenced without allocating memory for it.

Comment: @HansPassant Agreed for MSVC. Anway: From what do you conclude it's MSVC? Because there are "run-time" errors?

Comment: @rjayavrp It will just point to an element of the 1st parameter, if ever (see `man strtol()`).

Comment: thanks @alk. `The second argument (char **endptr) seems to be a waste of space!`  given in man page. so confused.

Comment: @alk - this runtime diagnostic is an MSVC feature.

Answer (score 1):

The `%lld` format specifier is for a `long long`.  You've declared a `long int` so may be trying to write to a larger type than you have storage for.  The effects of this are undefined but writing over the next stack variable is very likely if `sizeof(long int) != sizeof(long long)` on your platform.

You can fix this by either changing `tempID` to be of type `long int` or by changing the format specifier you use to `%ld`.

Comment: @user1892265 I've updated my answer with a couple of options to fix this error.  Note that you may then find further errors.  alk's answer points out one of them

Comment: i've corrected those mistakes, but still whenever i try to input the new Data (whether its ID, Name etc... it still gets stuck

Comment: Can you add logging to determine which line you get stuck on?  Or explain what you mean by 'stuck' if program execution doesn't hang?  e.g. does the program exit unexpectedly?

Comment: It does not exit unexpectedly, it just hangs in there, without continuing the execution of the program!

Comment: It doesnt exit unexpectdly... it just stays there like its waiting for something, and then this notification pops in MSVC:
First-chance exception at 0x60A4B49C (msvcr110d.dll) in C - Assignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.